# IntelliJ, remove scrollbar

Tags: intellij-idea, scrollbar, jetbrains-ide

Especially when using split screen in JetBrains products, the scrollbar often gets in the way and takes up important screen real estate. Is there a way to disable it? I cannot find an option in IntelliJ/JetBrains-IDE settings.

Comment: Note also that scrollbar behaviour (e.g. you can set it to hide when not scrolling) can be customized in OS settings, see e.g. it in General settings for mac.

Comment: @Andrey yes, but that OS setting doesn't seem to be propagated to IntelliJ.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no *actual* way to disable the scrollbar. However, one can go into

```
Color Scheme > General > Vertical Scrollbar > *
```

and turn **Background** property to `Opacity: 0`

[image: background]

I cannot find an option for the horizontal scrollbar.